# Using an openload server for free

Tags: internet

So, I want to make my own website for watching movies and TV shows but not in English but in my native language. So I was wondering is it legal to just upload videos from the openload server or some other server to my website. Do I have to pay for an openload account or something or does openload just let me upload their videos for free. It might be a stupid question but I am really not familiar with this subject and if you have any tips for building my movie watching website what would be great. Thanks!!!

Comment: Do you have a license to distribute the content?  What you are proposing sounds very much like copyright infringement, especially as OpenLoad has been hit several times over the past few years for large scale copyright infringement - if they don't have a license to distribute the content they offer, then in turn you do not have a license to distribute their content.  Unless you have negotiated a license with the content owners separately - have you?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you hold the copyright or a specific license for the materials you wish to use or distribute, this is universally accepted as copyright infringement. It is actually known as criminal intellectual property (IP) rights infringement in the UK - [constituting piracy](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/intellectual-property-crime-and-infringement#criminal-offences-counterfeiting-and-piracy).

> Openload, one of the largest file-hosting sites on the Internet, has
> agreed to shut down its service. Openload.co and several related
> domains, including Streamango, now show a banner confirming that they
> have been taken over by global anti-piracy coalition ACE.

[here](https://torrentfreak.com/openload-and-others-taken-down-by-anti-piracy-alliance-ace-191031/).

You can find out more about this on a global basis, from ACE [here](https://www.alliance4creativity.com/).